# How can I configure PHP with my Tomcat

Tags: php, apache, tomcat

I have installed tomcat succesfully but if I want to use some php code. So where should I put this php code in my tomcat directory and how I can configure php with tomcat. Any suggestions or link will be appreciated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP/Java bridge as mentioned in the other answer is one option. The other would be to use the PHP runtime built in Java called [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/)

Comment: The internet never ceases to amaze me.

Comment: Quercus is an amazing tool to integrate PHP and java. And it can run PHP faster than Apache.

Answer (score 4):

Tomcat is a [Java Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) Container first - it wasn't built to run PHP natively. There are however adapters, which allow you to run PHP on Tomcat, e.g.

- http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/tomcat6.php

If you only need to run PHP, you might be better off using a [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) like setup.