# How I can install on tomcat php+oracle?

Tags: php, oracle, tomcat

I have Redhat server. On this server is installed Oracle. Tomcat is instaled too for Java.

Now I need install php, and then connect it to oracle. How can I do that? Its possible make Tomcat+Php+Oracle?

Thanks beforehand for all answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I configure PHP with my Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500312/how-can-i-configure-php-with-my-tomcat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Nico is correct in saying this is the same question as asked elewhere on SO, the answers there are not very good.

Tomcat is intended as a minimal environment for running Java in - it is not a generic webserver. It does support CGI, and so will PHP - but even before considering the fact you seem to be using an Oracle database, this is going to be painfully slow. Really you want PHP to be invoked as a module or fastCGI - but Tomcat does not support these (Quercus is no a serious option).

If you want to run both Java and PHP on the same server then use a proper webserver (apache or nginx) to front the 2 application servers.